# How can i change the image and center it

Tags: css, flexbox

how can I change the picture and center it against the flexbox?

I tried to add the width and height but to strangely move and do not see png.
I also care about responsive
Thank you for your help

CSS CODE

```
.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
    border-top: 4px solid rgb(134, 17, 212);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    padding-top: 15px;
    background: rgb(20, 20, 19);
}

.contact, .projects, .me{
    background: rgb(20, 20, 19);
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    color: white;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}

.contact {
    background: url('cntct.png') top center no-repeat;
    width:
}
```

HTML CODE

```
  <div class="container">
        <div class="contact">Kontakt</div>
        <div class="projects">Projekty</div>
        <div class="me">O mnie</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

[image]

Comment: do not forget post html code

Comment: Hi, we need to see the HTML as well if we're going to provide assistance, otherwise we're just guessing. Please edit your question to add the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a picture of what you want it to look like? Without that, I can suggest adding `background-size: 50px, auto, contain;` to size the background image. Here's an example using a sample contact image:

```css
  .container{
        width: 100%;
        height: 50vh;
        border-top: 4px solid rgb(134, 17, 212);
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        padding-top: 15px;
        background: rgb(20, 20, 19);
    }
    
    .contact, .projects, .me{
        background: rgb(20, 20, 19);
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        color: white;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        font-size: 1.3em;
    }
    
    .contact {
        background: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/13/17/30/mail-1454732_960_720.png') top center no-repeat;
        background-size: 50px, auto, contain;
        
    }
```

```html
      <div class="container">
            <div class="contact">Kontakt</div>
            <div class="projects">Projekty</div>
            <div class="me">O mnie</div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

You can also position it anywhere in the flexbox: `background: url('cntct.png') 50% 25px no-repeat;` for instance:

[image]